# Bypass memory corruption limitations

Tags: c, security, audit

Assuming you are security code auditing guy and you have been got into some 
code like this:

```
if(strlen(data) < 100) {
     strcpy(buffer, data);
}
```

What would you do in order to corrupt the buffer?
Is that possible? if so, how? and why dont using that condition for code security?

Comment: How is `buffer` defined?

Comment: Why don't you use strncpy with a parameter based on how large `buffer` is rather than the if statement you've got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obvious answer is if `buffer` isn't at least **101** `chars` long, a specific case of which is when the programmer forgot that the null-terminator is copied as well (if the `buffer` is exactly **100** `chars` long). There are two more subtle attack vectors I can see off the top of my head:

1. `data` may border on non-readable memory and not contain a null-terminator. This would cause a segmentation fault or access violation, but not memory corruption directly.
2. `data` and `buffer` could overlap when treated as strings. The behavior is undefined in this case.

As an example of the second attack, take the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char someImportantString[] = "Something that should not be overwritten";
    char buffer[101] = "\0goodbye cruel world";
    char data[16] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o',' ','w','o','r','l','d',
                     'x','x','x','x','x'};                         

    if(strlen(data) < 100)
    {
         printf("Probably not good\n");
         strcpy(buffer, data);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The likely result of this is overwriting a lot of memory and then seg-faulting.